# StackedColumn chart and group items with different X-axis names

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

How can i group different x-axis names into 1 and give new name to grouped values and SUM of grouped values?

**Example:**

My table:

```
Name GroupBy    Value
A    100        35,9
F1   120        9,4
F2   120        10,4
F3   120         5,7
H1   130        30,2
I1    70        72,7
P1   150        72,7
V1   110        19,8
```

How to group F1, F2 and F3 names and values?

- I want to group F1, F2 and F3 into F (see img)
- X-axis- column Name
- Y-axis- column Value
- Group by- column GroupBy

Expected Chart:

[image: Expected Chart]

Comment: What you do so far add some code

Comment: dont have code for stacked column chart only for classic column chart. Example table si datasource for my classic column chart(x-axis: Name, y-axis: Value) from example table. I want to know how to group for example F1,F2 and F3 and result will be **SUM** of F1,F2 and F and new Name will be **F**. Look at this img: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kRGKc.png

Comment: When you define series there may be property for stacked, do you checked it?

Comment: i know how to change stacked column property but i don't know how to group by x-axis. I need to know how to group different names. If you have same columns for example F1 and F1 than stacked chart join this 2 columns into one but i want to join columns F1 and F2 and that is problem for me.